# Android 4.1 NullPointerException between activities

Tags: java, android, mobile, null, android-activity

i keep getting thrown a NullPointer Exception in Android 4.1 while switching between Activities. Any thoughts on why?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

    Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    Button join = (Button)findViewById(R.id.join_button);  

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);    
        startActivity(i);   
        }});//END OF CLICK

    join.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, JoinActivity.class); 
        startActivity(i);   
        }});//END OF CLICK

}
```

Comment: Paste the Logcat of the NullPointerException.

Comment: does it happen from both JoinActivity and LoginActivity?

Comment: Show us the stack trace. Almost always it will point to the exact line.

Comment: We really need some kind of stack trace here

Comment: @FoamGuy just login activity. Here is the stack trace

`E/AndroidRuntime(625): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(625): at com.novipal.main.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:23)`

Answer (score 2):

From your question description i am assuming that you are getting this error because, you haven't add LoginActivity & JoinActivity both these activity into your AndroidManifest.xml. Just add them into AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".JoinActivity"></activity>
```